# Problema con librería spotipy

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy trabajando con la librería Spotipy en Python y estoy tratando de obtener los tracks de unas listas de reproducción pero cuando llega a una lista me dice que esa lista no existe pero en Spotify dice que si, este es el código que tengo:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

#Show tracks
def show_tracks(results):
    for i, item in enumerate(results['items']):
        track = item['track']
        if track != None:    
            print("%d %s %s" % (i, track['artists'][0]['name'], track['name']))
        else:
            pass

#Auth
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(
        client_id = '******', 
        client_secret = '*******')  

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager = client_credentials_manager)

user = 'lucy.cgtz'
playlists = spotify.user_playlists(user)


#Show the list and next show the tracks
while playlists:
    for i, playlist in enumerate(playlists['items']):
        print("%4d %s %s" % (i + 1 + playlists['offset'], playlist['uri'],  playlist['name']))
        results = spotify.user_playlist(user, playlist['id'], fields="tracks,next")
        tracks = results['tracks']
        show_tracks(tracks)
        while tracks['next']:
            tracks = spotify.next(tracks)
    if playlists['next']:
        playlists = spotify.next(playlists)
    else:
        playlists = None
```

Aquí dejo una imagen de lo que obtengo como error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Luis en qué linea obtienes el error y cual es este? ¿Es en la línea `results = spotify.user_playlist`?

Comment: @FJSevilla en si no es error en ninguna linea de código es al momento de ejecutarlo, al principio corre de manera normal pero llega  aun punto donde el programa falla.

Comment: Consejo: Encapsula la parte que crees que da error (justo despues del while, creo) con `try:` #aqui tu código `except Exception as e: print(e)` y ejecutalo, este truquillo nos ayudará a identificar el problema. ¿Qué error da? (Nota: También puedes encapsular todo el programa en un try except pero así es más dificil localizar el error exacto).

Comment: @Saelyth acabo de agregar una imagen del error que me da, saludos.

Comment: Nunca he usado spotipy pero me da la impresión de que le pides `next` a todos los objetos de tu lista para construir la URL de la siguiente playlists, pero llegará un punto en el que alcanzarás la última playlist y obviamente no habrá una despues, en cuyo caso deberías eliminar el parametro next de la ultima url. En caso de no ser esto, recomendarías que investigues a fondo la playlist que falla para ver si tiene propiedades ocultas como "playlist no pública" o caracteres extraños como nuestra famosa Ñ que a veces da problemas de decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al parecer encontré el problema, lo que pasaba es que algunos usuarios tienen canciones de otras listas que no son de ellos por eso marca el error de que no lo encuentra pero aquí dejo el código al cual se le hizo la modificación de cambiar `user` por `playlist['owner']['id']` gracias a todos los que aportaron.

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

#Show tracks
def show_tracks(results):
    for i, item in enumerate(results['items']):
        track = item['track']
        if track != None:    
            print("%d %s: %s" % (i, track['artists'][0]['name'], track['name']))
        else:
            pass

#Auth
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(
        client_id = '*****', 
        client_secret = '*****')  

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager = client_credentials_manager)

user = 'lucy.cgtz'

playlists = spotify.user_playlists(user)


#Show the list and next show the tracks
while playlists:
    for i, playlist in enumerate(playlists['items']):
        print("%4d %s %s" % (i + 1 + playlists['offset'], playlist['uri'],  playlist['name']))
        results = spotify.user_playlist(playlist['owner']['id'], playlist['id'], fields="tracks, next")
        tracks = results['tracks']
        show_tracks(tracks)
        while tracks['next']:
            tracks = spotify.next(tracks)
            show_tracks(tracks)
    if playlists['next']:
           playlists = spotify.next(playlists)
    else:
        playlists = None
```